# implode explode in php

Tags: php

This is my code-

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
   echo $days= $row['attending_days'];
  echo $days1 = explode($days',');
  echo count($days1);
```

it will show me the only one value

Comment: Not nearly enough information for us to answer. What is `$sql1`?

Comment: what's the query in $sql1? what data is in the field 'attending_days' (``var_dump($row['attending_days'])``?

Comment: Buddy, put some efforts in your question.

Comment: Do you get any error? you should, because you switched position of arguments for explode (delimiter comes first).And I suppose you made a type here by not separating the args.

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
   $days= $row['attending_days'];
   $days1 = explode(',' , trim($days));
   echo count($days1);
}
```

why are you using echo with all lines?

Comment: thanks dear but its will show me +1 entery like when w enter two date then it wil show us 3 attending dates is the dates which enter by the user when user enter 2 dates it count 3. can you tell me what can ido

Comment: thanks buddy for your soltuion but while is not woking thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Despite the rather poor amount of information in your question, I think the problem is down to your arguments being backwards in your call to explode (which appears to be mistyped)

http://au.php.net/explode

> Although implode() can, for historical
>   reasons, accept its parameters in
>   either order, explode() cannot. You
>   must ensure that the delimiter
>   argument comes before the string
>   argument.

The call should be delimiter then array - `explode(',', $days);`

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array function only fetch single array from result set. If you want to fetch all result set you can use this

```
$rows = array();    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Maybe he just needs one row, who knows